# How change google based map in jquery mobile OpenLayers

Tags: jquery, mobile

Hye All,

please help me, im develop jquery mobile openlayers and based map in BING, how i want to change based map to google?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using google.maps as shown here would be help.
http://ol3js.org/en/master/examples/google-map.html?q=google